# Generate QA dataset from large text corpus

Tags: natural-language-processing, python, datasets

I have a corpus of a domain data in form of 10-15 books pdf and some articles and my end-goal is to make a question-answering system particular to that domain.
For that, I would need a dataset on Q/A which I can use on top of something like SQuAD(**S**tanford **Qu**estion **A**nswering **D**ataset) for domain-specific knowledge

My stuck point is *how to convert this corpus into a usable question-answering dataset*.

My current strategy is something **AllenAI** has been working with. A list of their research papers on it can be found [here](https://allenai.org/aristo/)

As I understand they use a combination of *Knowledge Extraction*, *Natural Language Understanding*, and *Inference* to get the job done. But I cannot find any good practical implementation.

Where can I find a good resource?